# How to see log in attendances in calendar

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a project in RoR. I have a log in feature and i want, for example, a user log in and the date when he did it can be seen on a calendar. Also i want a user to see all his log in attendances on a calendar. Could any one give me an idea how to do it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [public activity](https://github.com/pokonski/public_activity) gem to record user activity.
Here's a [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/406-public-activity) for it.

The hard part would prob be how to get it to record
everytime you log in, it would depend on what login approach you use, it usually should have some method that gets called that you could slip in activity logging logic in.

Putting it on a calendar is a whole different story though, would recommend looking for some jquery calendar plugins that accepts json, and have rails spit out the user activity in json format.

You'll probably have to customize the jquery plugin to fit your needs.